# Making "class " work in tkinter

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

Ive been trying to get a Class work in pythons Tkinter. 
But when calling it with "if *name* == "*main*" " something simply doesnt work if you have any solution for this problem Id appreciate it alot.If you have any solution that doesnt involve the "IF" statement that I used please tell me .

```
class Calculo:
     def _init_(self,parent):

        def calcular_moduloV1(self):
                if Vel_in_y.get()>0 and Angulo_desp.get():
                    self.modulo = Vel_in_y.get()* math.sin(math.radians(Angulo_desp.get()))  
                    label = tkinter.Label(frame,text=self.modulo)
                    label.pack()
        def calcular_moduloV2(self):
            if Vel_in_x.get()>0 and Vel_in_y.get()>0 and self.modulo == 0:
                self.modulos = math.sqrt(Vel_in_x.get()**2+ Vel_in_y.get()**2)
                label = tkinter.Label(frame,text=self.modulos)
                label.pack()
        def calcular_anguloD(self):
            if Vel_in_y.get()>0 and Vel_in_x.get()>0:
                self.angulo = math.degrees(math.tanh(Vel_in_y.get()/Vel_in_x.get()))
                label = tkinter.Label(frame,text=self.angulo)
                label.pack()
        def calcular_Vel_in_y(self):
            if Angulo_desp.get()>0 and Velocidad_in.get()>0 and Vel_in_y.get()==0:
                self.Vel_y = Velocidad_in.get()*math.sin(math.radians(Angulo_desp.get()))
                label = tkinter.Label(frame,text=self.Vel_y)
                label.pack()
        def calcular_Vel_in_x(self):
            if Angulo_desp.get()>0 and Velocidad_in.get()>0 and Vel_in_x.get()==0:
                self.Vel_x= Velocidad_in.get()*math.cos(math.radians(Angulo_desp.get()))
                label = tkinter.Label(frame,text=self.Vel_x)
                label.pack()

        button = tkinter.Button(frame,text='respuesta' ,command = 
                                (self.calcular_moduloV1,self.calcular_moduloV2,self.calcular_anguloD,self.calcular_Vel_in_y,self.calcular_Vel_in_x))
        button.pack()
if _name_ == "_main_":
    window =tkinter.Tk()
    myapp = Calculo(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

(This is just a fragment of the code ...if you need the  whole thing send me a message THANKS!!!)

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__"`. Double underscores on each side

Comment: What error do you get when running that script?

Comment: The problem is that the class never runs (even if i put the double underscores)

Comment: Are you sure you put the double underscores on both sides of the operator?

Comment: If you will only run it from that file, you don't need if clause. Do you know why do you use that phrase?

Answer (score 0):

Few comments.

First

`def _init_(self,parent):`

should be

`def __init__(self,parent):`

Second, as others pointed out:
`_name_ == "_main_"`

should be

`__name__ == "__main__"`

Third. This button does not make sense (especially the command):

```
    button = tkinter.Button(frame,text='respuesta' ,command = 
                     (self.calcular_moduloV1, self.calcular_moduloV2,self.calcular_anguloD, self.calcular_Vel_in_y,self.calcular_Vel_in_x))
button.pack()
```

What do you want to achieve here? frame is also not defined.

Forth, `def calcular_moduloV1(self):` has wrong indentation in the body.